# What are the differences between Scala’s inner classes and Java’s Inner/nested classes?

Tags: java, scala, oop

How does Scala handle inner classes differently to Java's nested, static or non-static, classes?

Comment: What do you mean by handle? At the end of the day Scala classes are just Java classes.

Comment: No. Scala classes are Scala classes. On one particular implementation of Scala, Scala classes may or may not be encoded as JVM(!!!) classes, but that does not mean that Scala classes are JVM classes and it certainly does not mean that Scala classes are Java classes. In particular, on the old Scala.NET port, the current Scala.js port and the future Scala-native port, Scala classes have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Java classes at all. Not in the slightest.

Answer (score 13):

The major difference is that if you have

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    def foo(x: Inner): Inner = this // just for the example below
  }
}
```

and two instances of `Outer`:

```
val a = new Outer
val b = new Outer
```

then `a.Inner` and `b.Inner` are two *different* types (where in Java they'd both be `Outer.Inner`), so that you can't do

```
val aInner = new a.Inner
val bInner = new b.Inner
aInner.foo(bInner)
```

They do have a common supertype which is written `Outer#Inner`.

Answer (score 8):

Scala has proper nested classes, just like they were originally invented in Beta. Java's inner classes are not nested classes. The main difference is that nested classes are nested in the enclosing *object*, not merely an inner class inside the enclosing *class*. IOW: a nested class is a runtime *instance* property of an *object* of the enclosing class, and just like two different instances of the same class have identically named but different valued instance variables (fields), they also have identically named but different valued nested classes.

IOW, `foo.SomeInnerClass` and `bar.SomeInnerClass` are different classes and not type-compatible.

Comment: What do you mean by *Java's inner classes are not nested classes*? What are they then?

Comment: They are inner classes.

Comment: What you be the precise definition of a *nested class*?

Comment: For a more detailed explanation with examples, please refer to [Scala tour](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html) page about this theme.