# ScalaTest: referencing NoArgTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am playing around with [sharing fixtures](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures), especially withFixture(NoArgTest). However, my code does not compile if referencing NoArgTest.

My only dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code trying to reference NoArgTest as a type:

```
1    class Example {
2      def foo(test: org.scalatest.TestSuite) = "foo"
3      def bar(test: org.scalatest.TestSuite.NoArgTest) = "bar"
4    }
```

mvn compile:

```
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.8
[WARNING]  org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.0 requires scala version: 2.11.8
[WARNING]  org.scalactic:scalactic_2.11:3.0.0 requires scala version: 2.11.8
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8 requires scala version: 2.11.8
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.5 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
```

...

```
[ERROR] Example.scala:4: error: object TestSuite is not a member of package org.scalatest
[ERROR] Note: trait TestSuite exists, but it has no companion object.
[ERROR]   def bar(test: org.scalatest.TestSuite.NoArgTest) = "bar"
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `TestSuite#NoArgTest` (this is the common type of all `NoArgTest`s independent of the suite), or `suite.NoArgTest` if you already have an instance `suite: TestSuite`. Note that if `suite` is a member parameter, they need to be in separate parameter lists:

```
def bar(suite: TestSuite)(test: suite.NoArgTest) = ...
```

See the answers to [What are the differences between Scala’s inner classes and Java’s Inner/nested classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690394/what-are-the-differences-between-scala-s-inner-classes-and-java-s-inner-nested-c/) for more details.